# Differintegral using Fourier Transforms in multivariate functions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

So I know that the Fourier Transform of a function $f(t)$, denoted $\mathcal{F}[f(t)]$ can be used to compute derivatives (and integrals) of $f(t)$, including of non-integer order like so:

$$
\frac{d^n f(t)}{dt^n} = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{(i\omega)^n \mathcal{F}[f(t)]\}
$$

where $\omega$ is the frequency variable. This is known from the properties of the fourier transform, however, I was thinking about how to generalize this for higher-dimensions. Higher dimensional functions $f(\vec r)$ have more interesting differential operators like gradients $\nabla f(\vec r)$ and Laplacians $\nabla^2 f(\vec r)$ and I was wondering how to use the principle stated in the equation above to compute these quantities.

Comment: [See here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/the-fourier-transform/), Remark 2.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you place an Answer so that I can close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this blog post of Terry Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/the-fourier-transform/), Remark 2.